# Multiple choice question about limits and continuity? (Or, $\tan x$ is continuous?!)

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, continuity

I'm doing a test about limits and continuity and got these two wrong.

> $\mathbf{Q1}$: The function $f(x) = \tan x$:
>   $\hspace{1em}\mathtt{a)}$ is continuous
>   $\hspace{1em}\mathtt{b)}$ is discontinuous
>   $\hspace{1em}\mathtt{c)}$ is increasing
>   $\hspace{1em}\mathtt{d)}$ is even

According to my professor the right one is $\mathtt{a)}$, but I don't see how $\tan x$ can be continuous. In fact, my answer was $\mathtt{b)}$, because it's discontinuous at $x = \frac\pi2 + k\pi$, with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is there a definition of continuity according to which $\tan x$ is continuous?

> $\mathbf{Q2}$: Between the following, select the correct sentence
>   $\hspace{1em}\mathtt{a)}$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ then $f$ is increasing
>   $\hspace{1em}\mathtt{b)}$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ then there exist an half line $(r, +\infty)$ on which $f$ can be inverted
>   $\hspace{1em}\mathtt{c)}$ the fact that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ does not imply that $f$'s domain contains half lines of the form $(r, +\infty)$
>   $\hspace{1em}\mathtt{d)}$ if $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ and $f$ can be inverted, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to +\infty}f^{-1}(x) = +\infty$

Here the correct one is $\mathtt{c)}$, while I replied $\mathtt{d)}$. I thought that given the premises in $\mathtt{d)}$, $f$ would be monotone increasing and thus $f^{-1}$ would be as well. Examples: $\exp(x)$ and $\ln x$, $x$ and $x$, $x^2$ (with $x > 0$) and $\sqrt{x}$...

Apart from $\mathtt{a)}$, which is obviously wrong, can you explain me the other answers?

Comment: $\tan x$ is continuous on its domain. IMO, it is a poorly worded question as is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $\tan$ function is defined on $\Bbb R\setminus \left\{\frac{\pi}2+k\pi,\; k\in\Bbb Z\right\}$ and it's continuous on this set. You can't say that this function is discontinuous on $\frac{\pi}2+k\pi$ since it isn't even defined on these points.

Comment: If it says this then it's wrong!

Comment: Thanks Sami. It appears I didn't know the definition of continuity very well. Do you have some hints for the second question as well?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so my initial comments were wrong.  A function can be labeled continuous or discontinuous at a point only if it is first defined at the point.  Think about the definition of continuity:

A function $f$ is **continuous at $x \in \mathbb{R}$** if:

> $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that for all $y \in \Bbb R$ with $|x - y|<\delta$ it follows that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

This definition uses $f(x)$, so $f$ *must* be defined here.

Similarly, negating the above definition tells us when a function is *discontinuous* at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  A function $f(x)$ is **discontinuous at a point $x \in \mathbb{R}$** if:

> $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\forall \delta > 0$ $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|x - y| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(y)| \geq \epsilon$.

This definition also uses $f(x)$, so $f$ should be defined at the point $x$ in order to be discontinuous at it.

So, $\tan{x}$ is continuous everywhere that it is defined.  On, for example, $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$, $\tan{x}$ is not defined, and therefore we cannot talk about continuity or discontinuity at this point.

Comment: Ok, it seems I was wrong too. Thank you for the explanation. Minor typo: shouldn't it be $y \in \mathbb{R}$ in both lines? Also, do you have some clues about the second question?

Comment: "$f(x)$ has to be defined at $x=a$ in order to be discontinuous at $x=a$." Are you claiming $f(x)=\begin{cases}-1, &x<0,\\ 1, &x>0,\end{cases}$ is continuous at $x=0$? Or $g(x)={\sin x\over x}$ is continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: @JohnD I'm saying $f(x) = \begin{cases} -1 & x < 0 \\ 1 & x > 0  \end{cases}$ is continuous on its domain.  We cannot talk about it being continuous or discontinuous at $x = 0$ because it isn't defined there.  I did say, very specifically, that "A function can be labeled continuous or discontinuous at a point only if it is first defined at the point."

Answer (score 1):

About the second question, the answer (d) is valid if you are dealing with a continuous function. Here, the trick is that the function $f$ can be discontinuous.

I remember a good example someone showed me a little while ago. The trick is to construct a function that splits on the sides of the $y$-axis. With such a function (that has to be a bijection) we can clearly see that the $f^{-1}$ function has no limit for ${x \to +\infty}$

Here is one:

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R_+}$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}2\lfloor x\rfloor + \{x\}&\quad x\ge0\\
2\lfloor -x \rfloor - 1 + \{x\}&\quad x < 0\end{cases}$$

Where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the integer part of $x$ and $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

Edit : It also work for the question (b) I think. Since $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ but you cannot chose a half line $(r,+\infty)$ where $f$ can be inverted (because it will be discontinuous on the half line and you will be missing the part before the half line to have it inverted).

Comment: This is very interesting. I didn't consider this case! I think that your function can be written more simply as: $$f(x) = \begin{cases}x + \lfloor x\rfloor&\quad x\ge0\\
x-3\lfloor x + 1\rfloor&\quad x < 0\end{cases}$$ Since $\{x\} = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$

Comment: for $b)$ a simple continuous counter-example is $f(x)=x+2\sin x$.

Comment: @DavidPeterson: Thank you, it does indeed fit the case!